# unable to download image form S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bukcet url of an image. I am trying to download this image using urllib or wget, in both cases code executes successfully, but corrupt image is downloaded. When i say corrupt, I mean that for a 2MB image a 200kb only get downloaded.

`urllib.urlretrieve(str(sys.argv[1]), "data/img"+str(randomword(10))+".jpg")`

In the later part of line, I am just adding random string as the name of the image that is to be downloaded.

Pls help

Comment: Have you checked the response? the image that is saved might actually be an aws xml response saying it failed due to permissions or something. Try open the image with a text editor to see if that's the case.

Comment: yes, I have received an xml response saying `Access Denied`
`Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>`

Comment: How could i get over with this

Comment: You would need to alter the permissions on the file in the s3 bucket so that public access is available. Maybe some of the info here will help https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5050

Comment: Could i not authenticate user with secret key first and then download?

Comment: Use `boto` library for AWS stuff...

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the file by authenticating first and downloading. I'd recommend just using python boto library to deal with amazon web services. If you did that the code would look something like this

```
import boto

# set your AWS creds on your environment path or hardcode it
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_KEY_ID") 
AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")

conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY)

bucket = conn.get_bucket("my_bucket_name")

key = bucket.get_key('file_on_s3.txt')
key.get_contents_to_filename('where_file_goes_locally.txt')
```

If you really don't want to use boto, you can piece it together manually and essentially do what boto does build up the right request headers from your aws creds. I do this using a bash script on a server I have. This should point you in the right direction (https://gist.github.com/davidejones/d05f51df75e659111227) if you want to rewrite this with python requests or urllib that should work too.